# "Unsupported GeoJSON type" from AJAX request to PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, openlayers, geojson, php, ajax

I'm trying to use a GeoJSON to build a layer on an OpenLayers map of MultiPolygons from my PostGIS database.

However the following error is thrown:

```
Uncaught Error: Unsupported GeoJSON type: undefined

b_                     GeoJSON.js:323
readFeatureFromObject  GeoJSON.js:113
readFeaturesFromObject GeoJSON.js:157
readFeatures           JSONFeature.js:54
<anonymous>            prova.js:19
```

I've already tried to check the GeoJSON on [GeoJSONlint](https://geojsonlint.com/) as suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419352/uncaught-error-unsupported-geojson-type-undefined-openlayers?rq=1), but it gives right hand rule error. I've tried to fix this using[this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259944/polygons-and-multipolygons-should-follow-the-right-hand-rule), but the error was in my coordinates, as [@pavlos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/60673/pavlos) noted and corrected.

I've also  tried to correct the [feature projection](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300199/openlayers-geojson-projection-issue/300206), but the error persist.

This is the PHP script that is called by AJAX:

```
<?php
    $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=root dbname=benilun");
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connessione PostgreSQL fallita.");
    };
    $res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT json_build_object( 'type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json) )
FROM ( SELECT id, identificazione, area FROM luogo ) as t(id, name, geom);");
    echo json_encode(pg_fetch_row($res));
?>
```

This is the JavaScript which should build the OpenLayers map; I've updated it with a [@JGH](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/84870/jgh) suggestion, that doesn't change the error but is indeed more correct:

```
var res;
var dati = new FormData();
$.ajax({
    url: "php/prova.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dati,
    success: function (resJ) {
        res = JSON.parse(resJ);
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.VectorSource({
          features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(res, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})
        });
        var stile = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'red',
              width: 1,
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
            }),
        });
        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.VectorLayer({
          source: vectorSource,
          style: stile
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
                vectorLayer
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([15, 15]),
                zoom: 4
            })
        });
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

And this is the GeoJSON object that is sent as response to the AJAX interrogation (suggested by [@TomazicM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm), in the last edit I forgot the object):

```
{
  "type" : "FeatureCollection",
  "features" : [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type":"MultiPolygon",
      "coordinates":[[[[10,30],[30,30],[30,60],[10,10],[10,30]]]]
    },
    "properties": {"id": 1, "name": "Parrocchia Santa Caterina"}
  }]
}
```

Could you help me?

Comment: This does not look valid `[[[[10,30],[10,10],[10,30],[30,10],[10,30]]]]` with 1st and 3rd vertex both being (10,30).

Comment: Thanks @user30184 , I've corrected the points but the error still persist.

Comment: Please edit your question and put back GeoJSON data sample that you removed on your last edit.

Comment: I think your coordinates is the problem. Try to change this --> `"coordinates":[[[[10,30],[30,30],[30,10],[10,10],[10,30]]]]` to this --> `"coordinates":[[[[10,30],[30,30],[30,60],[10,10],[10,30]]]]`. Consider that to shape a polygon you have to respect the right hand rule.

Comment: @pavlos I've changed the coordinates as you said, now GeoJSONlint doesn't return the right hand rule error, but error in JavaScript is again the same.

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the res object in the success function? If you haven't then add `console.log(res);` after the line `res = JSON.parse(resJ);` and check the output in the browser console

Comment: @Dataform yes, I've tried an alert and the result is the object I've putted in the question.

Comment: @DandozWar are you sure it is only the object and not an array with one object? `pg_fetch_row` returns an array with each column, so i think your api returns an array. You can try to add `console.log(Array.isArray(res));` and see if it is true. You can also just add `res = res[0];` after `res = JSON.parse(resJ);` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@Dataform](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/137252/dataform) comment I've finally figured out what the error was.

The type of GeoJSON was Undefined because I was passing an array cointaining the GeoJSON. In the php script the method`pg_fetch_row` returns an array, in order to send the GeoJSON I have to send only its first element.

Here the corrected php script:

```
<?php
    $conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=root dbname=benilun");
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connessione PostgreSQL fallita.");
    };
    $res = pg_query($conn, "SELECT json_build_object( 'type', 'FeatureCollection', 'features', json_agg(ST_AsGeoJSON(t.*)::json) )
FROM ( SELECT id, identificazione, area FROM luogo ) as t(id, name, geom);");
    $obj_arr = pg_fetch_row($res);
    echo json_encode($obj_arr[0]);
?>
```

In addition I've corrected some more errors in the usage of OpenLayers, here the updated version of the JavaScript code:

```
var res;
var dati = new FormData();
$.ajax({
    url: "php/prova.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: dati,
    success: function (resJ) {
        res = JSON.parse(resJ);
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
          features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(res, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})
        });
        var stile = new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: 'red',
              width: 1,
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1)',
            }),
        });
        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: vectorSource,
          style: stile
        });
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),
                vectorLayer
            ],
            view: new ol.View({
                padding: [40, 40, 40, 40]
            })
        });
        
        map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent())
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript will not wait for the ajax call to return before continuing processing your code. The only thing that will happen once the Ajax call is completed is `success: function (resJ) { res = JSON.parse(resJ); }`, but it is too late, the map is already loaded with an empty json (the initial content of `restJ`).

You will want to load the layer after the Ajax call is completed. You can put all the code that comes after the `$.ajax({..})` (i.e. the code creating the layers, the map etc) inside a function, and call this function from within the `success:` section.

Comment: But `async` option is set to false, so that shouldn't be the reason.

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the info. I'm not JQuery user, so I trusted the code I saw. And your comment is actually answer to the question.

Comment: @JGH Putting the layer creation in the success function is a good idea indeed so I've done it, but it still doesn't work and the error is the same.